# How do I ignore escape characters in command line arguments?

Tags: command-line, f#

Consider a simple F# console application that echoes the command line arguments passed to it, one command per line:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    argv |> Array.iter (printfn "%s")
    0
```

If I pass this program a directory path with a trailing slash, it treats the slash as an escape character producing unexpected results:

```
> app.exe "c:\some path\" "c:\another path"
c:\some path" c:\another
path
```

How can I retrieve the command line arguments without interpreting a slash as an escape character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Environment.CommandLine` gives you access to the complete unescaped command line, and you are free to process that however you like.

But unless you plan to implement a full-blown parser in your app, this is not going to be a reliable approach, and it's unlikely you will be able to reliably handle all of the byzantine escaping rules implemented by all of the various shells your app might have been invoked in.  e.g. `cmd.exe` escapes things differently from `powershell.exe`, which is in turn different from Cygwin, etc etc.

A better choice is to simply take `argv` as-is, validate it as you see fit (e.g. `File.Exists(argv.[0])` or whatever), and bail out with a helpful error message if the user messed something up.

Comment: Thanks! Good point about the different escaping behaviour in various shells - I was only considering `cmd.exe`.